# Como usar 2 submit separadamente em html?

Tags: php, html, html5

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de upload, porém quando dou submit no código a seguir ambos trocam o valor da variável ID.

A minha idéia é trocar o valor do ID para que a pasta que irá ser feita o upload do arquivo mude, como pode ser visto no 1º echo, enquanto no 2º echo mostra o botão de upload em si.

Quero que apenas o 1º echo mude o valor do ID quando eu usar o submit.

```
echo "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='text' name='ID' id='ID' placeholder='INSIRA O ID'>
    <input type='submit' value='confirmar' id='ID'>";
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    echo "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='allfiles' />
    <input type='submit'/>
    </form>";
```

Comment: Não entendi porque você tem dois `form` e só um deles é fechado. Você consegue explicar ?

Comment: pois eles estavam juntos anteriormente, porém isso não interfere nesse caso pelo que testei.

Comment: Testei seu código aqui, e tá funcionando normal. Ou eu não entendi direito sua dúvida. Eu preencho por exemplo '12' no formulário, e é isso que a var `$ID` recebe, não é trocado por outro valor.

Comment: sim o 12 é recebido com sucesso, porém depois de inserir o 12 e usar o botão enviar do outro form que no caso é de upload ele troca o valor do ID novamente o que não era pra acontecer.

Comment: Você tentou dar o atributo `name` diferente pra cada form desse?

Comment: sim, acabei de tentar trocar o submit pelo button e também não funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separei em 2 `forms` diferentes. Acho que isso resolve seu problema:

```
    echo 
    "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='text' name='ID' id='ID' placeholder='INSIRA O ID'>
        <input type='submit' value='confirmar' id='ID'>   
    </form>";
    $ID = $_POST['ID'];
    echo 
    "<form action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type='hidden' name='ID' value='{$ID}'>
        <input type='file' name='allfiles' />
        <input type='submit'/>
    </form>";
```

Comment: não entendi o objetivo dessa linha input hidden

Comment: Ela pega o `$ID` que veio do primeiro `form` e guarda no segundo `form` em um campo escondido. Você testou o código ?

Comment: sim, funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa fechar o primeiro `</form>`pois do jeito que esta seu código tudo é um formulário só, e ao clicar em qualquer submit todos os dados são submetidos.

Quando clicar no confirmar do 1º formulário ele gera um POST, vamos chama-lo de POST_1, e quando o 2º formulário é submetido, chamaremos de POST_2, o POST_1 não existe mais e seus dados também não, o que existe agora é o POST_2. É como se você atualizasse a pagina depois de enviar o form, ou seja a memoria é recriada do zero.

O que você pode fazer:
Salvar em algum lugar(BD ou SESSION) a informação do `id` que vem no POST_1 e recuperá-la para usar no POST_2.

Enviar os posts para paginas php diferentes, o que teria a necessidade de salvar o id do mesmo jeito.

Enviar tudo em um formulário só.